# App Parent Folder Permissions in Entity Framework

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I have a WPF app that uses Entity Framework to connect to a SQL database.  Upon compilation of the app I copy the files over to the published location where I have a number of apps, for example:

I:\Apps\App1\[App Files]

I:\Apps\App2\[App Files]

etc, etc....

Where I is a mapped network drive mapped via GPO.

If a user has access to the folder represented by I:\ then the app loads fine.  If however the user only has access to the subfolder where the app is located then the app loads but they receive an exception:

The Underlying provider failed to open... Network or instance specific error occurred...

Does anyone know why this is?  I don't really want to grant access to the I:\ portion of the drive.

Thanks in advance!